# How To Replace Strings With X to Y Characters

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I have data similar to the following:

```
2496,8805,1/7/19 18:58,9723308800
7,18538320322,1/7/19 19:22,13012881250
8827,9723308808,1/7/19 19:55,9723308800
3109,8801,1/7/19 19:56,19723308800
```

I am looking for a way to replace strings in field 2. If the number does not have 10-11 characters, I would like to replace it with 12223334444 so the output would be:

```
2496,12223334444,1/7/19 18:58,9723308800
7,18538320322,1/7/19 19:22,13012881250
8827,9723308808,1/7/19 19:55,9723308800
3109,12223334444,1/7/19 19:56,19723308800
```

My original thought was to use `cut` to get the second field and then use `grep "[1-9]"` or something similar to match 9 characters or less. However, I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way to do this using `sed` or `awk`. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2<1000000000 || $2>99999999999 {$2=12223334444} {print}' file
```

or shorter:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2<1000000000 || $2>99999999999 {$2=12223334444}1' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} length($2)<10 || length($2)>11 {$2=12223334444}1' file
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {l=length($2)} l<10 || l>11 {$2=12223334444}1' file
```

or

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{l=length($2)} l<10 || l>11 {$2=12223334444}1' file
```

Output:

```
2496 12223334444 1/7/19 18:58 9723308800
7,18538320322,1/7/19 19:22,13012881250
8827,9723308808,1/7/19 19:55,9723308800
3109 12223334444 1/7/19 19:56 19723308800
```

---

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)

Comment: Never use a variable named `l` as it looks far too much like the number `1` (indistinguishable in some fonts) and so unnecessarily obfuscates your code.

Answer (score 2):

another `awk`

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} (s=length($2))!=10 && s!=11{$2=12223334444}1' file
```

or

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} (s=length($2))<10 || s>11{$2=12223334444}1' file
```

can be golfed further

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} $2!~/^.{10,11}$/{$2=12223334444}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^[^,]*,[^,]{10,11},/!s/[^,]*/12223334444/2' file
```

If the second field delimited by `,` does not have 10 or 11 characters, replace the field by `12223334444`.

Comment: @WalterA I'm afraid not. The regex matches the positive condition n.b. the `!`.